# How to accelerate scipy.map_coordinates for multiple interpolations?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, ndimage

I have several values f, g, h that are defined on the same regular grid  (x, y, z) that I want to interpolate onto a new grid (x1, y1, z1). i.e., I have f(x, y, z) , g(x, y, z) , h(x, y, z) and I want to calculate f(x1, y1, z1), g(x1, y1, z1), h(x1, y1, z1).

I am using `scipy.map_coordinates` at the moment. However, each interpolation is done separately and the number of points are around 4,000,000, so it is quite slow

```
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
import numpy as np

# examples of f, g, h
f=np.random.randn(100,50,50)
g=np.random.randn(100,50,50)
h=np.random.randn(100,50,50)

# examples of x1, y1, z1
x1=np.random.rand(4000000)*100
y1=np.random.rand(4000000)*50
z1=np.random.rand(4000000)*50

# my solution at the moment
coords=np.array([x1,y1,z1])

out = np.zeros((3, coords.shape[1]))
out[0]= map_coordinates(f, coords, order=1)
out[1]= map_coordinates(g, coords, order=1)
out[2]= map_coordinates(h, coords, order=1)
```

Is there a way to accelerate the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a short comment on @Han-Kwang Nienhuys answer.
The main thing to improve here is to avoid vectorized commands, which can lead to a quite high performance degradation.

Generally it would be a good idea to change the array shapes of input and output (n,3) instead (3,n) if you use default C-ordered arrays.

**Input**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates

# examples of f, g, h
f=np.random.randn(100,50,50)
g=np.random.randn(100,50,50)
h=np.random.randn(100,50,50)

n=4_000_000
# examples of x1, y1, z1
x1=np.random.rand(n)*99
y1=np.random.rand(n)*49
z1=np.random.rand(n)*49

coords=np.array((x1,y1,z1))
fgh = np.array([f, g, h]).T.copy().T # optimize memory layout
```

**Code**

```
#from Han-Kwang Nienhuys
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mymap(ars, coords):
    """ars is input arrays, shape (m, nx, ny, nz)
    coords is coordinate array, float, shape (3, n)
    """
    # these have shape (n, 3)
    ijk = coords.T.astype(np.int16)
    fijk = (coords.T - ijk).astype(np.float32)
    n = ijk.shape[0]
    m = ars.shape[0]
    out = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.float64)

    for l in range(n):
        i0, j0, k0 = ijk[l, :3]
        # Note: don't write i1, j1, k1 = ijk[l, :3]+1 -- much slower.
        i1, j1, k1 = i0+1, j0+1, k0+1
        fi1, fj1, fk1 = fijk[l, :3]
        fi0, fj0, fk0 = 1-fi1, 1-fj1, 1-fk1
        out[l, :] = (
            fi0 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[:, i0, j0, k0] +
            fi0 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[:, i0, j0, k1] +
            fi0 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[:, i0, j1, k0] +
            fi0 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[:, i0, j1, k1] +
            fi1 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[:, i1, j0, k0] +
            fi1 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[:, i1, j0, k1] +
            fi1 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[:, i1, j1, k0] +
            fi1 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[:, i1, j1, k1]
            )
    return out.T

#optimized version
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=False)
def mymap_opt(ars, coords):
    """ars is input arrays, shape (m, nx, ny, nz)
    coords is coordinate array, float, shape (3, n)
    """
    # these have shape (n, 3)
    ijk = coords.T.astype(np.int16)
    fijk = (coords.T - ijk).astype(np.float32)
    n = ijk.shape[0]
    m = ars.shape[0]
    out = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.float64)

    for l in nb.prange(n):
        i0= ijk[l, 0]
        j0= ijk[l, 1]
        k0 =ijk[l, 2]
        # Note: don't write i1, j1, k1 = ijk[l, :3]+1 -- much slower.
        i1, j1, k1 = i0+1, j0+1, k0+1
        fi1=  fijk[l, 0] 
        fj1=  fijk[l, 1] 
        fk1 = fijk[l, 2]

        fi0, fj0, fk0 = 1-fi1, 1-fj1, 1-fk1
        for i in range(ars.shape[0]):
            out[l, i] = (
                fi0 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[i, i0, j0, k0] +
                fi0 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[i, i0, j0, k1] +
                fi0 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[i, i0, j1, k0] +
                fi0 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[i, i0, j1, k1] +
                fi1 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[i, i1, j0, k0] +
                fi1 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[i, i1, j0, k1] +
                fi1 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[i, i1, j1, k0] +
                fi1 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[i, i1, j1, k1]
                )
    return out.T
```

**Timings**

```
out_1 = mymap(fgh, coords)
out_2 = mymap_opt(fgh, coords)
print(np.allclose(out_1,out_2))
#True

%timeit out = mymap(fgh, coords)
#1.09 s ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit out = mymap_opt(fgh, coords)
#parallel=True
#144 ms ± 5.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#parallel=False
#259 ms ± 4.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Regarding (n, 3) layout: I thought I did, but indeed `coords.T.astype(np.int16)` doesn't change the memory layout, so that requires another `.copy()`. I tried `parallel=True`, but it became so slow that I thought my IPython had crashed.

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a try, but unfortunately, it doesn't beat the `scipy map_coordinates` function. On my modest laptop, the three calls to `map_coordinates` take about 1.0 s together, which is 80 ns per array per coordinate tuple. With 300 clock cycles (3.7 GHz CPU), that sounds like a lot, but it turns out that there is quite a lot of work to do.

Part of the job is splitting the float coordinates into the integer parts and the fractional parts. This part of the job you need to execute only once for the three input arrays f, g, and h. Unfortunately, this would take only about 100 ms. There just is a lot of multiplication and addition to be done.

I implemented it using numba JIT compiled code, and took care to have array layouts in memory such that cache access is reasonably efficient, but it is still running 1.3 times slower than `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`. (Edit: max9111 provided a dramatic improvement in a separate answer.)

I changed your coord initalization to ensure that there is no out-of-bounds handling needed:

```
n = 4000_000
x1=np.random.rand(n)*99
y1=np.random.rand(n)*49
z1=np.random.rand(n)*49
```

The implementation:

```
from numba import njit

@njit(fastmath=True)
def mymap(ars, coords):
    """ars is input arrays, shape (m, nx, ny, nz)
    coords is coordinate array, float, shape (3, n)
    """
    # these have shape (n, 3)
    ijk = coords.T.astype(np.int16).copy() # copy for memory layout
    fijk = (coords.T - ijk).astype(np.float32)
    n = ijk.shape[0]
    m = ars.shape[0]
    out = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.float64)
    
    for l in range(n):
        i0, j0, k0 = ijk[l, :3]
        # Note: don't write i1, j1, k1 = ijk[l, :3]+1 -- much slower.
        i1, j1, k1 = i0+1, j0+1, k0+1
        fi1, fj1, fk1 = fijk[l, :3]
        fi0, fj0, fk0 = 1-fi1, 1-fj1, 1-fk1
        out[l, :] = (
            fi0 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[:, i0, j0, k0] +
            fi0 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[:, i0, j0, k1] +
            fi0 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[:, i0, j1, k0] +
            fi0 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[:, i0, j1, k1] +
            fi1 * fj0 * fk0 * ars[:, i1, j0, k0] +
            fi1 * fj0 * fk1 * ars[:, i1, j0, k1] +
            fi1 * fj1 * fk0 * ars[:, i1, j1, k0] +
            fi1 * fj1 * fk1 * ars[:, i1, j1, k1]
            )
    return out.T

fgh = np.array([f, g, h]).T.copy().T # optimize memory layout
out = mymap(fgh, coords)
```

Per coordinate tuple and per input array, there are 24 float multiplications and 7 float additions. In addition, there are a bunch of array indexings that require integer multiiplications. The amount of arithmetic that is shared between the input arrays is fairly small.

Comment: There is one performance critical "mistake" in your code. Every vectorized command is a for loop on its own. (8 single inner loops). You can simple join all 8 into one loop by explicitly writing out the inner loop. `for i in range(ars.shape[0]):` `out[l,i]=....` This gives a speedup of a factor of about 3. Than you can also parallelize the outer loop (`parallel=True`) and `for l in nb.prange(n):`. (another factor of 2). Additional speedup may also be achieved in completely avoiding the other vectorized commands, even if they look quite convenient in this example.

Comment: @max9111 I don't see how adding an explicitly inner loop will speed up the processing. Could you show more detailed code for this part?

Comment: @max9111 I expected that the JIT compiler would figure out how to handle `ars[:, i0, j0, k0]` with SIMD instructions without allocating new arrays, but I seem to be mistaken. Thanks.